# Removing undefined elements from new array mapped from nested array using map() and filter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to build several variables to be used later, each representing a specific array from within a series of nested arrays (basically a data array being used for several projects).

When I get to the selection of the array I need using `map()`, I get the new array containing `undefined` in each of the other parts of the array I wasn't mapping. This makes sense of course because the array still had the space indexed, the specific values there just weren't mapped. Where I'm struggling though is cleaning up that new array to remove those `undefined` entries. I'm trying to use `filter()`, but I'm open to alternative methods. Regardless of which method, I cannot eliminate all falsy values as some of these will need to be included. I only need to remove `undefined` entries.

```js
var data = {
  "cert_stat": [{
      Month: "Nov-2015",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 87.1,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 9.7,
      loOP_Percent_None: 3.2,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 62.7,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 20.2,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 17.3
    },
    {
      Month: "Feb-2016",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 83.9,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 19.9,
      loOP_Percent_None: 3.2,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 61.1,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 22.2,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 16.7
    }
  ],
  "reg_pk_xp": [{
      "Quarter": "Y1Q1",
      "Question_5": [{
          "Yes": 66
        },
        {
          "No": 7
        },
        {
          "Not Sure": 28
        },
        {
          "Total": 101
        }
      ],
      "Question_6": [{
          "Yes": 66
        },
        {
          "No": 7
        },
        {
          "Not Sure": 28
        },
        {
          "Total": 101
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y1Q2",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 30
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 13
      }, {
        "Total": 48
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 30
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 13
      }, {
        "Total": 48
      }]
    }
  ]
};

var q5_yes = data.reg_pk_xp.map(function(e) {
  return e.Question_5.map(function(e) {
    return e.Yes;
  });
});
console.log("Question_5 YES with UNDEF entries", q5_yes);


var q5_yes_filtered = q5_yes.filter(function(val) {
  return val !== undefined;
});
console.log("Question_5 YES only", q5_yes_filtered);

/*    IGNORE, PREVIOUS TEST 
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.reg_pk_xp.map(function(e) {
  return e.Question_5.map(function(e) {
    return e.Yes;
  });
});
      /PREVIOUS TESTS           */


q5_yes = q5_yes.filter(function(e) {
  return e !== undefined;
});
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = q5_yes;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TEST FILE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test">TEST</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="data.js"></script>
  <!--data.js file is normally a seperate, but local file-->
</body>

</html>
```

I'm thinking that the `filter()` method isn't acting where I think it is (on the `q5_yes` array), but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please shorten your code to just a [mcve] - there is far too much code where 3 entries would be enough to show the issue

Comment: A little trick for you, as long as everything else is valid JSON types, undefined is not a valid JSON type, so if you stringify and then parse, it will automatically remove all undefined..  eg.. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({removeme:undefined, keepme: true}))` will just return `{keepme:true}`..

Comment: Why are you using an array of objects, each with just one different key? Why not a single object like `{"Yes": 66, "No": 7, "Not sure": 28, "Total": 101}`?

Comment: I definitely prefer `JSON.parse` and `stringify` methods, but the rest of the data file (not included in the above sample) is not entirely valid JSON. I didn't get to work on the data file, but for anyone starting from scratch, making sure it's all valid JSON types is infinitely better and easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter isn't working because `q5_yes` is a 2-dimensional array, and the `undefined` elements are in the nested arrays. But you're filtering the top-level array.

```js
var data = {
  "reg_pk_xp": [{
      "Quarter": "Y1Q1",
      "Question_5": [{
          "Yes": 66
        },
        {
          "No": 7
        },
        {
          "Not Sure": 28
        },
        {
          "Total": 101
        }
      ],
      "Question_6": [{
          "Yes": 66
        },
        {
          "No": 7
        },
        {
          "Not Sure": 28
        },
        {
          "Total": 101
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y1Q2",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 30
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 13
      }, {
        "Total": 48
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 30
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 13
      }, {
        "Total": 48
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y1Q3",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 32
      }, {
        "No": 1
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 20
      }, {
        "Total": 53
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 21
      }, {
        "No": 9
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 23
      }, {
        "Total": 53
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y1Q4",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 79
      }, {
        "No": 7
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 12
      }, {
        "Total": 98
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 71
      }, {
        "No": 13
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 14
      }, {
        "Total": 98
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y2Q1",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 88
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 17
      }, {
        "Total": 110
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 60
      }, {
        "No": 33
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 17
      }, {
        "Total": 110
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y2Q2",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 94
      }, {
        "No": 9
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 14
      }, {
        "Total": 117
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 76
      }, {
        "No": 26
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 15
      }, {
        "Total": 117
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y2Q3",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 38
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 14
      }, {
        "Total": 57
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 23
      }, {
        "No": 23
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 11
      }, {
        "Total": 57
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y2Q4",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 48
      }, {
        "No": 2
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 12
      }, {
        "Total": 62
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 36
      }, {
        "No": 12
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 14
      }, {
        "Total": 62
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y3Q1",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 90
      }, {
        "No": 2
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 19
      }, {
        "Total": 111
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 62
      }, {
        "No": 32
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 17
      }, {
        "Total": 111
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y3Q2",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 55
      }, {
        "No": 3
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 19
      }, {
        "Total": 77
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 41
      }, {
        "No": 27
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 9
      }, {
        "Total": 77
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y3Q3",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 43
      }, {
        "No": 2
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 12
      }, {
        "Total": 57
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 29
      }, {
        "No": 12
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 16
      }, {
        "Total": 57
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y3Q4",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 40
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 18
      }, {
        "Total": 63
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 27
      }, {
        "No": 15
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 21
      }, {
        "Total": 63
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y4Q1",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 77
      }, {
        "No": 8
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 32
      }, {
        "Total": 117
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 51
      }, {
        "No": 41
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 25
      }, {
        "Total": 117
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Current contract to present", // Present: Y4Q1, 8/13/18
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 780
      }, {
        "No": 61
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 230
      }, {
        "Total": 1071
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 562
      }, {
        "No": 290
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 219
      }, {
        "Total": 1071
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Lifetime data to present", // Present: Y4Q1, 8/13/18
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 2409
      }, {
        "No": 297
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 658
      }, {
        "Total": 3364
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 1743
      }, {
        "No": 1047
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 574
      }, {
        "Total": 3364
      }]
    }
  ]
};

var q5_yes = data.reg_pk_xp.map(function(e) {
  return e.Question_5.map(function(e) {
    return e.Yes;
  });
});

var q5_yes_filtered = q5_yes.map(function(subarray) {
  return subarray.filter(function(val) {
    return val !== undefined;
  });
});
console.log("Question_5 YES only", q5_yes_filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed this:

```
return e.Yes !== undefined;
```

in this code:

```
var q5_yes = data.reg_pk_xp.map(function(e) {
  return e.Question_5.map(function(e) {
    return e.Yes;
  });
```

```js
var data = {
  "cert_stat": [{
      Month: "Nov-2015",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 87.1,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 9.7,
      loOP_Percent_None: 3.2,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 62.7,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 20.2,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 17.3
    },
    {
      Month: "Feb-2016",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 83.9,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 19.9,
      loOP_Percent_None: 3.2,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 61.1,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 22.2,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 16.7
    },
    {
      Month: "May-2016",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 95.2,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 4.8,
      loOP_Percent_None: 0,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 80.9,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 14.7,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 4.4
    },
    {
      Month: "Aug-2016",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 95.2,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 4.8,
      loOP_Percent_None: 0,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 83.6,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 11.9,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 4.5
    },
    {
      Month: "Nov-2016",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 91.9,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 8.1,
      loOP_Percent_None: 0,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 89.2,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 9.2,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 1.5
    },
    {
      Month: "Feb-2017",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 95.2,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 4.8,
      loOP_Percent_None: 0,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 90.2,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 7.8,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 1.5
    },
    {
      Month: "May-2017",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 95.2,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 4.8,
      loOP_Percent_None: 0,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 90.2,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 7.8,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 1.5
    },
    {
      Month: "Aug-2017",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 93.4,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 6.6,
      loOP_Percent_None: 0,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 80.7,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 17.5,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 1.8
    },
    {
      Month: "Nov-2017",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 96.7,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 3.3,
      loOP_Percent_None: 0,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 80.7,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 17.5,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 1.8
    },
    {
      Month: "Feb-2018",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 97.0,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 3.0,
      loOP_Percent_None: 0,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 81.0,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 17.0,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 2.0
    },
    {
      Month: "May-2018",
      loOP_Percent_Cert: 96.8,
      loOP_Percent_Exp: 3.2,
      loOP_Percent_None: 0,
      doW_R_Percent_Cert: 72.9,
      doW_R_Percent_Exp: 25.4,
      doW_R_Percent_None: 1.7
    }
  ],
  "reg_multi": [{
    "Networks": ["loOP", "NGH", "doW_R", "RES", "MTG", "ERGO", "Other"], //DO NOT CHANGE ORDER
    "Labels": ["None", "1-5", "6-10", "11-25", "More than 25"],
    "None": [846, 1442, 647, 1554, 1589, 1618, 1338],
    "1-5": [487, 231, 697, 126, 101, 69, 229],
    "6-10": [182, 17, 248, 10, 0, 3, 69],
    "11-25": [96, 1, 73, 1, 0, 0, 38],
    "More than 25": [80, 0, 26, 0, 1, 1, 17]
  }],
  "reg_pk_xp": [{
      "Quarter": "Y1Q1",
      "Question_5": [{
          "Yes": 66
        },
        {
          "No": 7
        },
        {
          "Not Sure": 28
        },
        {
          "Total": 101
        }
      ],
      "Question_6": [{
          "Yes": 66
        },
        {
          "No": 7
        },
        {
          "Not Sure": 28
        },
        {
          "Total": 101
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y1Q2",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 30
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 13
      }, {
        "Total": 48
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 30
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 13
      }, {
        "Total": 48
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y1Q3",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 32
      }, {
        "No": 1
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 20
      }, {
        "Total": 53
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 21
      }, {
        "No": 9
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 23
      }, {
        "Total": 53
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y1Q4",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 79
      }, {
        "No": 7
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 12
      }, {
        "Total": 98
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 71
      }, {
        "No": 13
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 14
      }, {
        "Total": 98
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y2Q1",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 88
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 17
      }, {
        "Total": 110
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 60
      }, {
        "No": 33
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 17
      }, {
        "Total": 110
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y2Q2",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 94
      }, {
        "No": 9
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 14
      }, {
        "Total": 117
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 76
      }, {
        "No": 26
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 15
      }, {
        "Total": 117
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y2Q3",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 38
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 14
      }, {
        "Total": 57
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 23
      }, {
        "No": 23
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 11
      }, {
        "Total": 57
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y2Q4",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 48
      }, {
        "No": 2
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 12
      }, {
        "Total": 62
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 36
      }, {
        "No": 12
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 14
      }, {
        "Total": 62
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y3Q1",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 90
      }, {
        "No": 2
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 19
      }, {
        "Total": 111
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 62
      }, {
        "No": 32
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 17
      }, {
        "Total": 111
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y3Q2",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 55
      }, {
        "No": 3
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 19
      }, {
        "Total": 77
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 41
      }, {
        "No": 27
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 9
      }, {
        "Total": 77
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y3Q3",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 43
      }, {
        "No": 2
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 12
      }, {
        "Total": 57
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 29
      }, {
        "No": 12
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 16
      }, {
        "Total": 57
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y3Q4",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 40
      }, {
        "No": 5
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 18
      }, {
        "Total": 63
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 27
      }, {
        "No": 15
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 21
      }, {
        "Total": 63
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Y4Q1",
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 77
      }, {
        "No": 8
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 32
      }, {
        "Total": 117
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 51
      }, {
        "No": 41
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 25
      }, {
        "Total": 117
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Current contract to present", // Present: Y4Q1, 8/13/18
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 780
      }, {
        "No": 61
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 230
      }, {
        "Total": 1071
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 562
      }, {
        "No": 290
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 219
      }, {
        "Total": 1071
      }]
    },
    {
      "Quarter": "Lifetime data to present", // Present: Y4Q1, 8/13/18
      "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 2409
      }, {
        "No": 297
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 658
      }, {
        "Total": 3364
      }],
      "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 1743
      }, {
        "No": 1047
      }, {
        "Not Sure": 574
      }, {
        "Total": 3364
      }]
    }
  ]
};

var q5_yes = data.reg_pk_xp.map(function(e) {
  return e.Question_5.filter(function(e) {
    return e.Yes !== undefined;
  });
});
console.log("Question_5 YES with UNDEF entries", q5_yes);


var q5_yes_filtered = q5_yes.filter(function(val) {
  return val !== undefined;
});
console.log("Question_5 YES only", q5_yes_filtered);

/*    IGNORE, PREVIOUS TEST 
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.reg_pk_xp.map(function(e) {
  return e.Question_5.map(function(e) {
    return e.Yes;
  });
});
      /PREVIOUS TESTS           */


q5_yes = q5_yes.filter(function(e) {
  return e !== undefined;
});
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = q5_yes;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TEST FILE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test">TEST</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="data.js"></script>
  <!--data.js file is normally a seperate, but local file-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What did you change/add?

Comment: Just modify this line `return e.Yes;` by this `return e.Yes !== undefined;
` @mplungjan