# Is there a more efficient way to write a set of methods and functions modifying the same variable one after the other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, methods

I have a series of items and reports which need to pull and modify sub-arrays from a lengthy JavaScript data file (which I can't modify). The sample below contains a snippet of an entry for demonstration-purposes assigned to the variable called `data`. I cannot in any way change the architecture of the data structure for `data` itself (in practice it is retrieved via a script tag `src="[URL]"` property), and other data beyond what is shown here does not appear to be 100% organized like a JSON file, if it makes a difference.

In the section below, I create a variable `q5_yes` which ultimately will hold a single array of values for the "Yes" responses from "Question_5" of a survey. To get it to the format I need though, I need to modify it in several steps.

While what I have below works on its own, I'm wondering if there's a better practice for combining these steps into a single one (and ideally makes it easier for re-use in the future as well since I'm going to be repeating this procedure a lot).

```js
var data = {
  "reSEQ": [{
    "Entry_1": "Nov-2015",
    "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 30
      },
      {
        "No": 5
      },
      {
        "Not Sure": 13
      },
      {
        "Total": 48
      }
    ],
    "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 30
      },
      {
        "No": 5
      },
      {
        "Not Sure": 13
      },
      {
        "Total": 48
      }
    ]
  }]
};

var q5_yes = data.reSEQ.map(function(e) {
  return e.Question_5.map(function(e) {
    return e.Yes;
  });
});

var q5_yes = q5_yes.map(function(subarray) {
  return subarray.filter(function(val) {
    return val !== undefined;
  });
});
var q5_yes = q5_yes.splice(0, q5_yes.length - 0);

var q5_yes = [].concat.apply([], q5_yes);
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = q5_yes;
```

```html
<div id="foo">test</div>
```

EDIT: I do have a solution to answer my own question, which is to simply wrap the var `q5_yes` calls into a single function with parameters to make it re-usable. It doesn't reduce the bloat of this section of code, but makes it easy when repeating the process for other entries.

Example:

```js
function getQuestion(question, answer){
 var arrayCon = data.reSEQ.map(function(e) {
  return e[question].map(function(e) {
   return e[answer];
  });
 });
 arrayCon = arrayCon.map(function(subarray) {
  return subarray.filter(function(val) {
   return val !== undefined;
  });
 });
 arrayCon = arrayCon.splice(0, arrayCon.length - 2); //removes current & lifetime entries
 arrayCon = [].concat.apply([], arrayCon);
 
 return arrayCon
}
```

And then I just create a var and set it to the function e.g. `var q5Value = getQuestion('Question_5', 'Yes')`

Comment: Why don't you change to a single object instead of an array of objects? The array of objects makes everything more complicated.

Comment: I suggested the same thing yesterday in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51866705/removing-undefined-elements-from-new-array-mapped-from-nested-array-using-map

Comment: Are you referring to the array in the variable `data`? I can't modify that per my question, that's maintained by others and I have no control over its formatting. I only have it inline with my code here for the example. If there's a way to do what you're saying "locally" e.g. modifying the formatting `data` after the file is loaded via the <script src="[URL]"> tag, then I'm afraid I don't know what that is, but would love to see how. Regardless, this question was more general in that I'm trying to make *my* code, such as it is, more concise (i.e. pretend `data` isn't even here).

Comment: I'm referring to the arrays like `[{Yes: 30}, {No: 5}, {"Not sure": 13}, {Total: 48}]`. Perhaps one of your first steps in processing the data should be to convert it to a single object: `{Yes: 30, No: 5, "Not sure": 13, Total: 48}`. Then the rest of the code will be easier, since you don't have to keep looping.

Comment: Aha, I see what you're saying now! Sorry for the confusion. I'm afraid I'm not much of a programmer, I'm just creating visualizations for reports from our data. I'm not sure how I would go about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getQuestion(question, answer){
 var arrayCon = data.reSEQ.map(function(e) {
  return e[question].map(function(e) {
   return e[answer];
  });
 });
 arrayCon = arrayCon.map(function(subarray) {
  return subarray.filter(function(val) {
   return val !== undefined;
  });
 });
 arrayCon = arrayCon.splice(0, arrayCon.length - 2); //removes current & lifetime entries
 arrayCon = [].concat.apply([], arrayCon);
 
 return arrayCon
}

var q5Value = getQuestion('Question_5', 'Yes') // to get the desired vals as an array
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the context of the problem, you can ensure that the mapping you want is located at the 0th index of each array, thus;

```js
var data = {
  "reSEQ": [{
    "Entry_1": "Nov-2015",
    "Question_5": [{
        "Yes": 30
      },
      {
        "No": 5
      },
      {
        "Not Sure": 13
      },
      {
        "Total": 48
      }
    ],
    "Question_6": [{
        "Yes": 30
      },
      {
        "No": 5
      },
      {
        "Not Sure": 13
      },
      {
        "Total": 48
      }
    ]
  }]
};

var q5_yes = data.reSEQ[0].Question_5[0].Yes;

document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = q5_yes;
```

```html
<div id="foo">test</div>
```

Comment: `q5_yes` would need to be the array of all values of "Yes" for all "Question_5"s for all Entry_N (of which there are actually several hundred). Your solution only pulls the value of the indexed entry (unless I'm misunderstanding it), and would need to be repeated for the other entries as well, no?